# Insert data from no render domain class attributes in grails app

Tags: grails, grails-domain-class

I try to insert into my database data from a domain class, but I only need to render two of domain class attributes and insert in my database default values for remainders attributes. How can I do this? I try why static mapping but no insert the data into the database. My Domain Class code is next:

```
class Syncronization {
    String name
    String url
    String startTime
    String lastSyncTime=null
    Integer cont

    static mapping = {
        startTime defaultValue: "'20000101T00:00:00'"
        cont defaultValue: 0
    }

    static constraints = {

        name(blank: false)
        url(blank: false)
        startTime nullable: true
        lastSyncTime nullable: true
        cont nullable: true
    }
}
```

In my `create.gsp`, I only render `name` and `url` fields, other fields I need set default values. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
class Syncronization {
    String name
    String url
    String startTime = "20000101T00:00:00"
    String lastSyncTime = null
    Integer cont = 0

    static constraints = {
        name(blank: false)
        url(blank: false)
        startTime nullable: true
        lastSyncTime nullable: true
        cont nullable: true
    }
}
```